# python turtle module gives slanted lines

Tags: python

```
for count, word in vk_list:
    bwidth = 600 / (len(vk_list) * 2 + 1)
    bheight = vk_list[index][0] / 6

    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.left(20)
    turtle.right(40)
    turtle.write(count)
    turtle.right(90)

    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(bheight)
    turtle.backward(40)
    turtle.end_fill()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LObKl.png)

Code is meant to draw histogram, but as I attached, this code gives me slanted lines, but I just can't understand it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`turtle.left` and `turtle.right` turn the turtle by the angle specified in the parenthesis

so `turtle.left(20)` changes the angle of the turtle by 20 degrees
hence the slanted lines

`turtle.forward` actually moves the turtle ahead

read the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#turtle.forward)

here's how you draw a 100*200 rectangle with a turtle

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(100)
t.left(90)
t.forward(200)
t.left(90)
t.forward(100)
t.left(90)
t.forward(200)
```